# Structs of Arrays: Type Error

Tags: julia

I do not get the difference between the following two struct definitions. The first works without any problems, while the second gives a Type Error:

```
julia> struct point1
           xy::Vector{Float64}
       end

julia> struct point2
           xy::Array{Float64,1}(2)
       end
ERROR: TypeError: point2: in type definition, expected Type, got Array{Float64,1}
Stacktrace:
 [1] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
 [2] eval(::Any) at ./boot.jl:234
 [3] macro expansion at /Users/.julia/v0.6/Atom/src/repl.jl:186 [inlined]
 [4] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `Array{Float64,1}(2)` isn't a type (i.e. `typeof(Array{Float64,1}(2)) != DataType`) but a newly initialized instance of a `Array{Float64,1}`.

If you would like to fix the dimension of the array field `xy` you can

1) make constructors throw errors/warnings if someone tries to initialize with an array of wrong size (this doesn't effect performance of course)

2) use [StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl) to maybe speed up your code

```
Pkg.add("StaticArrays")
using StaticArrays

struct point3
    xy::SVector{2,Float64}
end
```

Test:

```
julia> p = point3(@SVector rand(2))
point3([0.621778, 0.083348])

julia> p = point3(rand(2))
point3([0.737558, 0.405582])

julia> p = point3(rand(3))
ERROR: Dimension mismatch. Expected input array of length 2, got length 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
struct point2
    xy::Array{Float64,1}
end
```

The problem was the definition of the dimension ...